# Is it possible to set the status code while using render :text => proc

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails supports streaming text updates from w/in action controller:

```
render :text => proc { |response, output|
  10_000_000.times do |i|
    output.write("This is line #{i}\n")
  end
}
```

Similarly, text can be rendered w/ an http status code:

```
render :text => ":(", :status => 400
```

I am wondering, if inside the 10 million writes we encounter an error, is it possible to close the stream w/ a status code?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can close a stream by catching the error and breaking out of the proc. You can then pass an error message or simply close your stream. For example:

```
render :text => proc { |response, output|
  10_000_000.times do |i|
    begin
      output.write("This is line #{i}\n")
      raise StandardError, "reached line 100!" if i == 100
    rescue Exception => e
      response.status = 400
      output.write(e.message)
      break
    end
  end
}
```

Comment: I'd do a simple `rescue` there -- `rescue Exception` catches everything.

Comment: That has the effet of writing the error message back, which can then be handled by JS. But the HTTP status code will still be 200. Doing :status => 400 or :status => 404, etc causes the HTTP message to come back w/ a more accurate status code.

Comment: I also updated my code so that you can pass back a 400 response code on an error.

Comment: Unfortunately, the response.status = 400 does not work. You cannot alter the status of a streaming response.